# How to use common data for all view based on logged in person's role in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using code igniter. In my coding, I want common view for all the pages. In Login  controller I have menus according to the user. If I click the menu, It should redirect to the menu and also the menu list.
Login Controller::

```
public function index(){



     if($this->session->userdata('isLoggedIn')){


    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');                                           

                $data['user']=$this->login_model->user_menu($id);

                $data['admin']=$this->login_model->admin_menu($id);

                $this->load->view('user_view',$data);


     }
    else{   

         $this->show_login(false);
     }
 }
```

Menu Controller:

```
public function index()
{



        $this->load->view('user_view',$????);
        $this->load->view('Right_view',$data);  

}
```

The both index exists in different controllers.I need data from Login controller to Menu controller. I want to achieve this using library. Anybody guide me?

Comment: add the menu Controller in core folder and your login controller extends to Menu Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 optioins

one
appliation/core/my_core.php

```
class My_core extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $CI =& get_instance();

        $CI->load->library(array('session'));
    }

    public function validate_login(){
        //logic to validate login
    }

    public function add_data(){
        $data  = array(
                      //what you want
                      );
    }
}
```

normal_controller.php

```
class Normal_controller extends My_core{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->validate_login();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->add_data();

        $data;
        $this->load->view('view', $data);
    }
}
```

two
controller.php

```
class Normal_controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library(array('validate_login', 'session'));
    }

    public function index(){
        if( $this->validate_login->success()){
            redirect('user', 'refresh');
        }
        else{
            $data = array();
            $this->load->view('normal_view', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

controller user.php

```
class User extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library(array('validate_login', 'session'));
        $this->validate_login->run();
    }

    public function index(){
        $data;
        $this->load->view('user', $data);
    }
}
```

library validate_login.php

```
class Validate_login{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $CI =& get_instance();

        $CI->load->library('session');
    }

    public function login_c(){
        $CI->session->set_userdata('loged', true);
    }

    public function run(){
        if( $CI->session->userdata('loged') !== true){
            redirect(base_url());
        }
        else{
            $data = array(
                          //what you want
                         );
        }
    }

    public function success(){
        return ( $CI->session->userdata('loged') === true) ? true : false;
    }
}
```